# what happen when somebody calls super in constructor of a class that inherit from abstract class?

Tags: java, oop, abstract-class

I'd like to know what really happens when somebody calls java `super()` method in the constructor of a class that inherits from an abstract class. As we know it, an abstract class cannot be instantiated but `super` calls the constructor of the abstract class.

Let's take an example.

```
public abstract class Figure { // cant be instantiated
    private type firstAttribute;
    private type secondAttribute;

    public Figure(type firstAttribute, type secondAttribute) {
        this.fisrtAttribute = fisrtAttribute;
        this.fisrtAttribute = fisrtAttribute;
    }

    protected abstract void anyMethod();
}

class Rectangle extends Figure {
    public Rectangle(type firstAttribute, type secondAttribute) {
        
        /*
         * call the abstract class constructor but we know, a 
         * constructor is used to
         * instantiate class and we can't instantiate an abstract class
         */
        super(firstAttribute, secondAttribute);
        
        // then what really happen ?
    }

     @override
     ....
}
```

Comment: Abstract classes cannot be instantiated directly. That does not mean they don't have constructors. They're classes. You can instantiate them indirectly through their concrete subclasses (and those subclasses will call super, explicitly or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abstract base class initialised any properties you inherit in your concrete inheriting class, so you can avoid code duplication in the initialisation

Answer (score 3):

The confusion stems from the fact that calling the `super()` constructor doesn't actually instantiate the super class. It simply invokes the `super()` constructor. No more, no less.

This means that the code in the super constructor will be called when `super()` is called. You're correct that abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but invoking the super constructor from a subclass constructor doesn't count as instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

I executes the code in the constructor it calls.

There is no need to create an instance of the abstract class for that; after all, during constructor invocation, the instance of the class is never created already.